# SASS: is it possible to use variables as argument within change-color()?

Tags: css, sass

I need to change the alpha value of a SCSS variable color.

`change-color($myVariable, $alpha: .4);`

-> work fine.

But I have to use a variable value for the alpha argument. I've first tried with my CSS variable:

`change-color($myVariable, $alpha: var(--opacity));`

-> failed

I've tried to escape the variable:
`change-color($myVariable, $alpha: #{var(--opacity)});`

-> failed

I've tried then to use a SCSS variable:
`change-color($myVariable, $alpha: $opacity);`

-> failed

At least I've tried it with the escape method:
I've tried then to use a SCSS variable:
`change-color($myVariable, $alpha: #{$opacity});`

-> failed

I have no idea now…

NB: the error message is "Error: not enough arguments for `change-color'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of Sass to compile your CSS you can use the [rgba](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules#rgb) function to change the alpha value of a color

```
.class {
   $color: dodgerblue;
   color: rgba($color, .4); // using alpha value   
   color: rgba($color, var(--opacity)); // using css variable
}
```

If you are using an older version of Sass *that does not allow css variables* in the rgba function you need to write a small function to handle this (note! the uppercase Rgba is to bypass the case sensitive Sass function)

```
@function color-alpha($color, $alpha: 1){
    @if type-of($alpha) == number { 
        @return rgba($color, $alpha); 
    } @else { 
        @return Rgba(
            red($color), 
            green($color), 
            blue($color), 
            $alpha
        );
    }
}


.class {
    $color: dodgerblue;
    color: color-alpha($color, .4); // using alpha value 
    color: color-alpha($color, var(--opacity)) // using css variable
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jakob E !
We use an old node-sass, but the 1rst solution with the standard `rgba` function works!

We'll migrate to dart-sass soon I think, which should maybe resolve the `change-color`'s bug, but I don't need this in that case…